# General form of version string of java command

Tags: java, version

I must parse the version string given by `java --version`.
In my environment the answer is

```
openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-suse-105.12-x8664)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-suse-105.12-x8664, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The proper version seems to be `17.0.9` and the patch seems to be `0`.
But the second line suggests something different (patch 9?).

Also openjdk is for sure specific for open jdk.
What else could there be?
Is there always a build date?

Comment: This looks like potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Maybe data you are looking for is already one of properties known by JVM. To see them you can execute code like `System.getProperties().forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k+" -> "+v ));`. To get value of single property simply use `System.getProperty(propertyName)`.

Comment: True, this is an alternative. 
On the other hand,in the context i am, I must check versions for tools mostly not in java. 
So your suggestion is not applicable. 
So far I just process command line. 

The problem is, that java is special in that there is openjdk and proprietary versions I dont have access to. I hoped that anyone can tell me.

Comment: Another alternative for those non-java tools would be letting them parse response of your own java class which internally would read/use those properties. For instance you can have `class MyJavaVersionInfo{ ... }` and in its `main` method you can print info you *want* (based on system properties) and in a *way* you want (which would make parsing easier). So *instead* of parsing response of `java -version` you could parse result of `java -cp path/to/package/containing MyJavaVersionInfo`.

Comment: I see, yes... i could write an application in java just writing version information. 
The problem is, my application is a maven plugin.. difficult. ... 
Maybe I shell go back to your initial solution..